# Link error when declaring public static variables in C++

Tags: c++, static, linker, lnk2005

I have this class with variable configuration parameters. I want to include it in other classes: `JugadorHumano`, `JugadorIA`, `Main`, `PartidaClasica`, `PartidaMision`.

```
#pragma once

class Configuracion
{
public:
    static int MAX_ATAQUES;
    static int DIV_TERRITORIOS;
};

int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES = 5;
int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS = 3;
```

What I want is to be able to modify or read the values from the other classes. I can't declare a static variable and define it in the declaration. I can't let that variables without definition either because I get "Unresolved External" errors.

```
1>JugadorIA.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES" \
         (?MAX_ATAQUES@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>JugadorIA.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS" \
         (?DIV_TERRITORIOS@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES" \
         (?MAX_ATAQUES@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS" \
         (?DIV_TERRITORIOS@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>PartidaClasica.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES" \
         (?MAX_ATAQUES@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>PartidaClasica.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS" \
         (?DIV_TERRITORIOS@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>PartidaMision.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES" \
         (?MAX_ATAQUES@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>PartidaMision.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS" \
         (?DIV_TERRITORIOS@Configuracion@@2HA) already defined in JugadorHumano.obj
1>D:\Leire\My Dropbox\Carpetas compartidas\Compartidos Victor\Practicas POO II\P3\P3M10\Debug\P3M10.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

What should I do to avoid this redefinition I get? I can't figure it out and I can't find a similar problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should write the definitions in the cpp file, otherwise, once you include your header file into more than one C++ file(translation unit), you'll get redefinition errors. And #pragma once operates only within one translation unit. So you need a Configuration.cpp file with the following contents

```
#include "Configuracion.h"

int Configuracion::MAX_ATAQUES = 5;
int Configuracion::DIV_TERRITORIOS = 3;
```

Also, if your class contains only static member, you have the option of considering having a namespace instead of a class.

Comment: If you didn't want to modify them, you could make them const. All upper case names usually indicate const.

Comment: @armen: You saved my day. Now i need to go back and read about translation unit.

Answer (score 4):

Place the variable definitions in a source file and compile and link that separately.

The header should only contain declarations and inline functions.

The `#pragma once` protects a single TU (translation unit); it provides no protection against multiple independent TUs including (and therefore defining) the same variable.